# What am i doing wrong with django paginator

Tags: python, django, pagination, paginator

I'm trying to use django paginator by following the [official documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/pagination/). But it displays only "Page of ." 
What am I doing wrong?

There is my views.py:

```
from django.shortcuts import render, get_object_or_404, render_to_response
from django.utils import timezone
from django.core.paginator import Paginator, EmptyPage, PageNotAnInteger
from .models import Post

def post_list(request):
    posts = Post.objects.order_by('-created_date')
    return render(request, 'blog/post_list.html', {'posts': posts})

def post_detail(request, pk):
        post = get_object_or_404(Post, pk=pk)
        return render(request, 'blog/post_detail.html', {'post': post})

def listing(request):
    article_list = Post.objects.all()
    paginator = Paginator(article_list, 25) # Show 25 contacts per page

    page = request.GET.get('page')
    try:
        articles = paginator.page(page)
    except PageNotAnInteger:
        # If page is not an integer, deliver first page.
        articles = paginator.page(1)
    except EmptyPage:
        # If page is out of range (e.g. 9999), deliver last page of results.
       articles = paginator.page(paginator.num_pages)

    return render(request, 'blog/post_list.html', {'articles': articles})
```

And my post_list.html:

```
<div class="pagination">
    <span class="step-links">
        {% if articles.has_previous %}
            <a href="?page={{ articles.previous_page_number }}">previous</a>
        {% endif %}

        <span class="current">
            Page {{ articles.number }} of {{ articles.paginator.num_pages }}.
        </span>

        {% if articles.has_next %}
            <a href="?page={{ articles.next_page_number }}">next</a>
        {% endif %}
    </span>
</div>
```

Comment: Are you sure you aren't rendering the `post_list` view? Please post your URLs, and note the URL you are typing into your browser.

Comment: urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^$', views.post_list, name='post_list'),
    url(r'^post/(?P<pk>[0-9]+)/$', views.post_detail, name='post_detail'),
    ]

Comment: neither of those urls call your view so you either need to make a url to do that or call your view in some way

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're rendering the `post_list` view, rather than the `listing` view. You have two options:

1. Change your URLs so that the root URL points to the `listing` view:

   ```
   urlpatterns = [ 
       url(r'^$', views.listing, name='listing'), 
       url(r'^post/(?P<pk>[0-9]+)/$', views.post_detail, name='post_detail'), 
   ]
   ```
2. Create a new URL for the `listing` view.

   ```
   urlpatterns = [ 
       url(r'^$', views.post_list, name='post_list'), 
       url(r'^listing/$', views.listing, name='listing'),
       url(r'^post/(?P<pk>[0-9]+)/$', views.post_detail, name='post_detail'), 
   ]
   ```

Again, you should only do one of these things, not both.